# Search function fail

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I would like to search data in a textbox . Below is my code. I tried to search but nothing happen.

> If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
>               Me.SearchPanelId()
>           End If
>       End Sub

```
Private Sub SearchPanelId()
    Dim ConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT panelid, panelname, paneltype FROM PANEL_TABLE"
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text.Trim()) Then
                sql += " WHERE panelid LIKE @panelid + '%'"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@panelid", TextBox1.Text.Trim())
            End If
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            cmd.Connection = con
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                GridView1.DataSource = dt
                GridView1.DataBind()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub


Protected Sub Search(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.SearchPanelId()
End Sub

Protected Sub OnPaging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    Me.SearchPanelId()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the validation before you start creating objects. You need to check if that datatype of the ID is valid. I guessed that this was an Integer type but check your database. If I am wrong and the datatype is .VarChar then see the second rendition. :-) The Like keyword does not make any sense with a numeric field.

Don't use .AddWithValue See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications

A DataAdapter is not necessary. Just use the load method of the DataTable.

```
Private Sub SearchPanelId()
    Dim IDValue As Integer
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text.Trim()) OrElse Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text.Trim, IDValue) Then
        Return
    End If
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT panelid, panelname, paneltype FROM PANEL_TABLE WHERE panelid = @panelid", con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@panelid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IDValue
            con.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

If Id is a .VarChar

```
Private Sub SearchPanelId()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text.Trim()) Then
        Return
    End If
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT panelid, panelname, paneltype FROM PANEL_TABLE WHERE panelid Like @panelid", con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@panelid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text.Trim() & "%"
            con.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```